# Is there a method to retain flash cookie

Tags: flash, local-storage

I use an application which uses flash cookie to store some important information. This information is critical and should not be deleted. But I have observed that the flash cookie or the shared local object is getting deleted under the following situations.

1. When the local history(including cookies) are deleted by the browser.
2. When flash is upgraded in the system.

This is adversely affecting my application. Please let me know, if there is a way to forcefully retain the 'shared local object' by placing some kind of lock on it. It will be better if this can done programmatically.

Regards,
OnTheGo

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of doing this (and probably shouldn't be). If the information needs to be retained when users delete their browser history, you'll probably need to store it on the server side, or otherwise give the user some way of reestablishing the data if it gets removed.